# Xamarin forms navigating to login doesnt work after logging out

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So I have a `LoginPage` in my xamarin forms where the user can navigate to by opening the hamburger menu and its one of the `HomeMenuItems` in my `ListView`. When the user logs in I navigate back to HomePage and remove the `LoginPage` from the navigation stack:

```
var nextPage = new HomePage();
await this.Navigation.PushAsync(nextPage);
Navigation.RemovePage(this);
```

And also change the Hamburger navigation to add new HomeMenuItems like MyPage and Logout like:

```
var md = (MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage;
var menu = (MenuPage)md.Master;
menu.showmychildren();
```

And it works but when I log out I change back the Hamburger menu to the "logged out version" whenever I try to navigate to the `LoginPage` it navigates me to the  `HomePage` and I have no idea why it is doing that.

Navigating to LoginPage from hamburger menu:

```
public void hideall()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ucet_stack.IsVisible = false;
    ucet.IsVisible = false;
    photo_sack.IsVisible = false;
    photo.IsVisible = false;

    menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
    {
        new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Home, Title="> HomePage" },
        new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Login, Title="> Login" },
         new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Sponsors, Title="> Sponsors" }
    };

    ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;

    ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[0];

    ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;
        await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
    };
}
```

And I call:

```
var md = (MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage;
var menu = (MenuPage)md.Master;
menu.hideall();
```

after logging out.

Comment: "whenever I try to navigate to the LoginPage" - where is the code for this?

Comment: I´ve added more  examples to explain it.

Comment: why does HideAll call InitializeComponent()?  Is HideAll supposed to automatically navigate to Login, or does the user have to tap the Login button first?

Comment: it was a test on my end, InitializeComponent() wasnt originally there. HideAll is called after the user clicks the Log Out from the menu, it leads to the constructor of LoginPage where the logout is done, there the HideAll is called to switch back the menu (what the user supposed to see when he is not logged in)  and navigate to HomePage with pushasync.

Comment: that sounds very convoluted.  Why does the constructor of LoginPage handle the logout?  Why are you navigating to HomePage when they are not logged in?  Why display the menu at all if the user is not logged in?  Why not just display a modal Login page so the user has no choice to do anything but login?

Comment: Well tbh I have no idea what I am doing. I need to log out from the hamburger menu. so since its navigation I dont know if I am able to navigate to a method, so I navigated to a secondary LoginPage constructor that handles the log out. when the user is not logged in I am displaying the menu so the user can navigate to the login page or to another page called sponsors. The logging in is not a problem, the navigation messes up after logging out.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I reimagined my solution, but your post led me to it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on you description, I would give you some suggestions:

1.remove `InitializeComponent();` There is no need for you to call this method again.

2.If you want to `Navigating to LoginPage from hamburger menu` in method `hideall()`, you can try to change the order of items in `menuItems` :

```
menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
 {
    new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Login, Title="> Login" },
    new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Home, Title="> HomePage" },    
    new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Sponsors, Title="> Sponsors" }
 };
```

Put the Login item as the first element in the array. Once you reset `ListViewMenu.ItemsSource` in `MasterPage`, it will show the first page in your menuItems .

3.Through the question and your comments, I'm confused about where is your logOut button located? In the homeMenu? In the loginPage?

4.You navigate pages in the method `ListViewMenu.ItemSelected` and I think which page to navigate to is depending on the **id**, so you can add a **breakPoint** at the line         `await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);` and then check the id of SelectedItem to see if it is the `MenuItemType.Login` type when you navigate pages.